# HTML - Images Won't Align with Paragraph Text

Tags: html

When I have text beside an image and set them at the same point on the screen, why don't they align properly at the top of their containing div? The text appears to be a pixel or two lower than the image. Is it because of the hight of the text?

The site I am concerned with is below. I want the top of the head-shots to align with the top of the bios. Any ideas?

http://www.fiveholeforfood.com/the-team/

Answer (score 1):

That's because of the `line-height`

Answer (score 0):

The line- height is pushing it down a couple of px but if you want to keep that for ease of reading I'd give the paragraphs a -5px margin on the top

```
#content .single p {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: -5px;
```

Answer (score 0):

It rather seems to be font-related, perhaps the [ascent line](http://font.is/wallpaper/FontAnatomyWallpaper1920x1200.jpg) is pushing the font down.

If so, there's nothing that can be done about it except adjusting the margins & padding’s applied to your elements to move the text some pixels upwards. Changing fonts or maybe even font-sizes would ruin the effect though.